# Mock не подменяет объект вызова метода

Tags: java, spring-boot, юнит-тесты, junit, mockito

Зависимости

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

код теста

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@DisplayName("CreditProgramService test")
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class CreditProgramServiceTest {
@Mock
Service someService;

@InjectMocks
CreditProgramService creditProgramService;

@BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

}

@Test
void mytest(){
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

when(someService.get()).thenReturn(myObject);
creditProgramService.get(); 
verify(someService, times(1)).get();
}
}
```

когда доходит до строки creditProgramService.get(); поток выполнения переходит в метод get моего сервиса creditProgramService и внутри метода уже дергает someService.get() который возвращает **null** вместо myObject, который я указал в условии теста when.

почему так получается?

Answer (score 0):

@BeforeEach
public void init() {
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

}

это было лишним,
и это тоже @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)